# Using ON clause to JOIN tables with same column name

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, inner-join

I wanted to ask about the condition of an `ON` clause while joining tables:

```
SELECT c_User.ID
FROM c_User
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM c_Group 
    JOIN c_Member ON (c_Group.Group_Name LIKE 'mcp%')
    WHERE 
        c_Group.Name = c_Member.Parent_Name
        AND c_Member.Child_Name = c_User.Lower_User_Name
)
```

I know that tables `c_Member` and `c_Group` have one column with the same name, `Directory_ID`. What I expected was `c_Member` and `c_Group` to join on that column using something like:

```
c_Group JOIN c_Member ON (c_Group.Directory_ID = c_Member.Directory_ID)
WHERE c_Group.Group_Name like 'mcp%'
```

How is this condition able to match the rows?

```
c_Member ON (c_Group.Group_Name LIKE 'mcp%')
```

1. Is this is a shorter way of referring to two tables joining on a column with the same name, while applying the LIKE condition?
2. If so, then can such a style work for a table with multiple column names that are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM c_Group 
JOIN c_Member ON (c_Group.Group_Name LIKE 'mcp%')
WHERE 
    c_Group.Name = c_Member.Parent_Name
    AND c_Member.Child_Name = c_User.Lower_User_Name
```

This subquery works, but the way it is spelled makes it quite unclear:

- The join condition (`c_Group.Group_Name LIKE 'mcp%'`) is not actually not related to the table being joined (`c_Member`) ; what it actually does is apply filter on table `c_Group` that makes it filter on (there is no magic such as *shorter way of referring to two tables joining on a column with the same name, while applying the LIKE condition*). It would make more sense to move it to the `WHERE` clause (this would still be functionaly equivalent).
- On the other hand, the `WHERE` clause contains conditions that relate to the tables being joined (for example: `c_Group.Name = c_Member.Parent_Name`). A more sensible option would be to put them in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`.

Other remarks:

- when using `NOT EXISTS`, you usually would prefer `SELECT 1` instead of `SELECT *`, (most RDBMS will optimize this under the hood for you, but this makes the intent clearer).
- table aliases can be used to make the query more readable

I would suggest the following syntax for the query (which is basically syntaxically equivalent to the original, but a lot clearer):

```
SELECT u.ID
FROM c_User u
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM c_Group g 
    JOIN c_Member m ON g.Name = m.Parent_Name AND m.Child_Name = u.Lower_User_Name
    WHERE g.Group_Name LIKE 'mcp%'
)
```